# Do I need to install Jupyter notebook in every virtual environment?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pipenv, virtual-environment

I isolate my data science projects into virtual environments using `pipenv`. However, running a Jupyter notebok does not access the local environment and uses the default IPyKernel. I've [seen](https://gustavosaidler.com/how%20to/jupyter-venv/) that you can register virtual environments from within the environment, but this requires installing the `ipykernel` package which itself requires Jupyter!

Is there anyway to avoid this and just use a single Jupyter install for all virtual environments?

Comment: No.. You have to install separate jupyter notebook for each virtualenv. As a virtualenv is activated, the jupyter notebook installed for that particular virtualenv will be available in path.

Comment: Any idea why this is the case? Seems like a waste of disk space and requires configuring add-ons etc for each new project...

Comment: pip install puts all files in site_packages of virtualenv. All dependencies available in particular virtualenv will only be available in that particular jupyter notebook instance.

Comment: That gave me an idea to just add the virtual environment's `site_packages` to the Python path. Is this going to be regrettable?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you'd install jupyter once and do the following in your virtual environments:

```
pip install ipykernel  
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

This isn't enough when you're running multiple Python versions.
There's a guide here that tries to address this:
https://medium.com/@henriquebastos/the-definitive-guide-to-setup-my-python-workspace-628d68552e14

It's not 100% failsafe, but it can help you avoid reinstalling jupyter notebook all the time.

Comment: ipykernel depends on jupyter-core, so this effectivley just installs Jupyter again.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there are few problems when reinstall jupyter for each environment separately: i.e. `pip install jupyter jupyterlab` in new environments.

I had multiple issues (with and without Conda), where Jupyter would install packages to a different python environment when you use `!pip install a_package_name` within a cell. The shell environment still kept track of the non-environment python, and you can tell this by comparing the outputs of `!which python` and

```py
import sys
sys.executable
```

Therefore, when you tried to import the package, it would not be available, because the cells used the environment python/ kernel (as it detected the `venv` directory).

Comment: Just remember that ! really invoke the command in the system shell!  so it will invoke the base environment python instead of the virtual environment.  Therefore a safe approach is to use Python -m pip xxxxx   instead if you have multiple environments esp with different pythons/package versions.  I remembered anaconda does use links to minimize the same copy of codes. not sure for PIP VENV.  But since it is always likely you run into different python versions for different reasons, and just make your environments 100% separate, it is worth the initial trouble.